# How to change column value in Impala table using Impala SQL?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I was trying to update column value of my Impala table using:

```sql
UPDATE tablename SET supports = 'A B'
WHERE supports = 'A'
```

However, since my table is not a Kudu table, I'm getting an error.

I tried to use `ALTER` command, but couldn't find any good documentation.

Using `ALTER` should the query look something like this?

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER [COLUMN] support
SET supports = 'A B'
```

Comment: ALTER changes the structure of a table, not the data in the table

Comment: I have created a Kudu table instead for updating. Thanks @Kurt

Answer (score 0):

Why not rewrite all the data.

```
Insert overwrite mytab
Select supports from mytab where supports <>'A'
Union all
Select 'A B' from 
mytab where supports ='A'
```

Not a very efficient way but it will work.